# Content Security Policy: cannot load Google API in Chrome extension react

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am creating chrome extension using react and implementing google signup

so i added

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

in index.html

now when i build the code and deploy, chrome shows errors saying

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I am using **manifest version 3** file.

So i added

```
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
    }
```

but now this is showing

```
content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow remote scripts by design. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/xQmZLc8cu6Q/) for workarounds.

Answer (score -3):

I managed CSP with my nginx settings by adding headers to my response, such as -

I'm not sure what do you mean by **manifest version 3 file**

> add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';script-src
> 'self'; font-src *; manifest-src 'self'; object-src 'none';
> connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/
> https://*.googleapis.com/;";

Can you try adding this line to your code (your requirement) -

```
connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://*.googleapis.com/;
```

Comment: tried not working, i mentioned in the question as welll

Comment: It has already be marked as -1, what I meant is to try conject-src = https://apis.google.com, btw other comments seems more related to the topic.

Comment: Refer this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/#security-csp